# How to run custom function within another one?

Tags: java, android

i build complicated application on android studio and i have this code which i have to put it in another function upon click it:

```
                EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
                EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Room);
                EditText e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Date);
                EditText e4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Age);
                EditText e5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Height);
                EditText e6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Weight);
                EditText e7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SerumC);
                EditText e8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SUN);
                EditText e9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ALB);

                SResult.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                r11b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                iup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                alert.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                rup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                r11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                e1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e3.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e4.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e5.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e6.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e7.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e8.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e9.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                Male.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                Female.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                Black.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                NonBlack.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                Stable.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                NonStable.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                Scrlabel.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                clearH.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                clearHN.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                calcH.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                calcHN.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                menuH.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                menuHN.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                equatlab.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                r12equ.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                printC.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                printCH.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                homeC.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                homeCH.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                returnC.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                returnCH.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                par.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```

---

but as you see it's long one and with time i will face a hard problem to make any change in my app, so i need to store this in a custom function and upon click the button the action of this function start like this:

---

```
public class visistore {
EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
                EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Room);
                EditText e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Date);
                EditText e4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Age);
                EditText e5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Height);
                EditText e6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Weight);
                EditText e7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SerumC);
                EditText e8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SUN);
                EditText e9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ALB);

                SResult.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                r11b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                iup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                alert.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                rup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                r11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                e1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e3.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e4.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e5.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e6.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e7.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e8.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                e9.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                Male.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                Female.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                Black.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                NonBlack.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                Stable.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                NonStable.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                Scrlabel.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                clearH.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                clearHN.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                calcH.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                calcHN.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                menuH.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                menuHN.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                equatlab.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                r12equ.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                printC.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                printCH.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                homeC.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                homeCH.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                returnC.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                returnCH.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                par.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```

}

then, in my main activity :

```
      button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                return true;
            }
            if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
  visistore
  }
    return true;
        }
    });
```

**Is this right?! or if it's wrong so i need to correct me**

Comment: Um... by putting it in a method?? Not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: It means you want a function must work after click on a button

Comment: @tnw : it's not a problem , but with time and my app need this function in every button so i will build an app with 10 K lines !!! so it will be soooooo hard to change any thing so i need to store the function with and get it with one line

Comment: @Ishrat : yes like that

Comment: Then tnw was correct, putting the code into a method and calling it whenever a button is clicked will solve the problem

Comment: and how i will do one like this ?!

Comment: @amerhalem Do you need a tutorial on how to define a method??  I am genuinely baffled as to what the problem is that you're asking about here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

Comment: @tnw : i will edit my question then you can correct me

Comment: @amerhalem Nope, that is wrong. That is not how you define a method. Please refer to the links I provided above.

Comment: i'll , but if you can help me now, i appreciate that from you

Comment: Since I can't comment on a [deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781611/background-function-work-on-api-16-but-not-lower-than-16?noredirect=1#comment45839998_28781611) (the one about `setBackground`): You said `ok thanks, you don't need to give me -1 , this is my level on android !!` But **it wasn't me downloading**! You accused me, because I was the only one who tried to help you?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem correctly then , it is simple as Just define a `boolean isButtonClicked`

make this `isButtonClicked = true` onClick event

then put `if(isButtonClicked)` condition in your touchClick event.

Hope you got it

Comment: @Andrew Orobator Give you good solution, if you need code for that,, i can help please update.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to set an `OnTouchListener` but an `OnClickListener`. The in the `onClick()` method of the `OnClickListener` call the appropriate function.